# .save() hanging and only receiving _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

problem with saving to MongoDB database

This is my second time trying to post to a database, still new to it. I am receiving string from a html form and trying to save into the database. I have connected to mongodb successfully, setup my post route, setup my model and now trying to send the http request to save it to db. before setting up the model, I was able to console.log the data I received from my form. but after setting up the model and trying to get the route to save it to db, it just hangs. If i comment out the main.save(), and console.log(main), alll I get back is an _id.
i cant figure out where im going wrong with it

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const routes = require('../routes/routes')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))
app.use(routes)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port ' + port)
})
```

routes

```
const express = require('express')
const Main = require('../src/model')
const router = new express.Router()


router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const main = new Main(req.body)
    console.log(main)

    try{ 
        await main.save()
        res.status(201).send(main)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
        console.log('Not working!')
    }
})


module.exports = router
```

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Main = mongoose.model('Main', {
    total_check: {
        type: String
    }
})

module.exports = Main
```

receiving an _id, but hanging on .save()

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing whole `req.body` to the database. Change this `const main = new Main(req.body)` to this

```
let main= new Main({

 total_check:req.body.total_check

});
```

Just make sure you are receiving correct data from your frontend end or Postman.

Also `save` returns a callback so handle that as well

```
main.save((err,main)=>{
   if(err) {console.log(err) }
   else { res.status(201).send(main) }
});
```

Comment: Just remove async before (req,res) and it should work. Let me know

Comment: I have changed the code around, still doing the exact same thing, just hanging and no error.
from postman I am sending a JSON {  "total_check": "249" }

if I console.log "main" BEFORE the save, I get the output I want now, but it still gets hung up on the save

and I thought the Async/Await took care of the save() callback

Comment: If it’s hanging on save then the best bet would be to check the mongo connection. And for now instead of sending res in else part console.log(main) to see if it returns something or not